# How to find number of physical core in a Windows system with c++ code

Tags: windows, winapi

I tried this but it will shows number of logical processors only

```
    SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
GetSystemInfo(&sysinfo);
int numCPU = sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: These are all finds only number of logical processors. But I want Number of physical processor. anyone give code for c++

Comment: Nope, that's not true at all. You need to read closely.

Comment: Is there any other simple methods apart from this?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Maybe. You might be able to do it through WMI. What's so hard about calling GLPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958(v=vs.85).aspx:

> Note  For information about the physical processors shared by logical processors, call GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx with the RelationshipType parameter set to RelationProcessorPackage (3).

You can get the related hardware of the logical processors, and infer how many physical processors are there